# Add hidden data to HTML table

Tags: jquery, html

Is it possible to add hidden variables to a HTML table row?
Which can be accessed when processing each row in jQuery?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by hidden ? jQuery supports $( element).data('myvar', 'the value');

Comment: I want to be able to add data to table rows which isn't actually displayed to the user

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can add as row id,

```
<tr id="your value"><td></td></tr>
```

or on jquery

```
 <tr data-somedata="your value"><td></td></tr>
```

can use

```
$(this).data('somedata')
```

or you can make

```
<td class="hide"> your value</td>
```

and do some css like this

```
.hide{
display:none;
}
```

Comment: Awesome the second one is exactly what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

Like

```
<table>
   <tr id="theTargetRow" data-id="2">
      <td>My Name</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

and can be retrieved by

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
   $('#theTargetRow').data('id')   // 2

})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of binding data to html element is using data-atrribute, like `<tr data-employee="{emp_id:100,emp_name:John}"><td>....</td></tr>`
 later you can get or set the attribute using `$(tr).attr('data-employee') // Get The Data 
 $(tr).attr('data-employee',varEmployeeData) // Set the Employee Data`

You can also use Jquery .data method.

Answer (score 0):

add`style="display:none;"` in which data you want to hide i.e `tr` or `td` and you can access while processing each row
Also you can add some `class` i.e. `attr` `class="className"` and add CSS

```
.className{
display:none;
}
```